# C++ operator overloading resolution ambiguity

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Am trying to move an antique C++ code base from gcc 3.2 to gcc 4.1, as I have run into a few issues. Of all the issues, the following is left me clueless (I guess I spent too much time with Java or I might have forgotten the basics of C++ :-P ).

I have a template class

```
template < class T > class XVector < T >
{
   ...
   template < class T > T
   XVector < T >::getIncrement ()
   {
       ...
   }  
   template < class T > int
   XVector < T >::getValue (size_t index, T& value)
   {
      ...
      //The problematic line
      value = (T) (first_value + getIncrement())
                  * (long) (index - first_index);
      ....
   }
}
```

This class is based on the STL std::vector. I have a second class TypeValue and its defined as below which can hold one of int, long and their unsigned variants, float, double, std::string. Also overloads almost all possible operators.

```
class TypeValue
{
    union
    {
        long* _int_value;
        double* _real_value;
        string* _text_value;
    } _value;

    TypeValue();
    explicit TypeValue(long _long);
    explicit TypeValue(int _int);
    explicit TypeValue(unsigned long _ulong);
    ...
    //similarly for all the remaining supported types.
    TypeValue(const TypeValue& ) //Copy constructor

    virtual TypeValue& operator=(const TypeValue &rhs);
    TypeValue& operator+ (TypeValue& )const;
    TypeValue& operator* (TypeValue& )const;
    ...
    //For all the basic operators

    operator long() const;
    operator int() const;
    operator unsigned long() const;
    operator unsigned int() const;
    ...

}
```

And finally I have another class, lets call it the build_breaker, which creates an object as `XVector < TypeValue > a_variable;`. Now when I compile this on gcc 3.2 this compiles without any problems. But when I try compiling this on gcc 4.1 I get errors saying ambigous overload for `operator*` in the class `XVector` and the candidates being

```
operator*(long int, long int) 
operator*(int, long int) 
operator*(long unsigned int, long int) 
operator*(unsigned int, long int) 
operator*(double, long int) 
operator*(float, long int)
```

If the compiler said it had problems finding a match for T * long, that would have made sense, but, why is it trying to typecast it to native type and then perform the arithmetic operation?
Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your arithmetic operators should accept and return const references since they're const functions. Your assignment operator should accept a const reference, but having the method itself be const doesn't make much sense; it's an assignment operator, so it's supposed to modify the thing you call it on.

Comment: Slight correction, the assignment operator is declared as
<pre><code>
virtual TypeValue& operator=(const SdmsTypedValue &rhs);
</code></pre>

It is not a pure virtual, but has a method definition.

Comment: Don't "correct" it in the comments. Correct it for real by editing your question and making it right. And when you do that, please also remember that we've never seen "SdmsTypedValue" before; this is the first you've mentioned that type.

Comment: Rob, I have updated the code.
Sorry about SdmsTypedValue. That is the effect of Copy and paste. I guess I need to improve my code review skills.

Comment: Niel & Gorpik suggested that there were too many implicit conversions happening and wrecking havoc.
I reviewed the code further and I found that operator * was being used with int and size_t as the right hand side type. If one type was overloaded the others references were having problems finding the correct invocation.
So I had to overload the operator* for all the types that were on the RHS. Although it fixed the problems, but I am not sure if this is the optimal solution for this problem. Because I don't other developers coming after me to scratch their heads over my logic.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second operand type is `long [int]`. The first is `TypeValue`, I expect, but there is no operator`*` that takes those two exact types. There are lots of other type combinations for that operator, though, which the compiler can select by doing an implicit conversion on the first operand. The language allows the compiler to do that to try to find a match.

But which of the many conversions should it choose? The compiler has no way to choose whether `int` is better than `long int`. (You might argue that since the second operand is `long int`, that should be the preferred conversion target, but that's not the way things work.)

So, some advice: First, don't supply so many implicit conversions. Since the class can only hold `long`, `double`, and `string`, those are the only three conversions I'd supply. That alone probably won't solve your problem, but it may reduce the size of the error output and make other things more manageable.

Instead of converting `(index - first_index)` to type `long`, consider converting it to type `T` (i.e., `TypeValue`) instead, since that seems to be the operation you really wanted to perform in the first place.

Comment: Hi Rob,
When I overloaded the operator* as TypeValue& operator* (const long&), the compiler gave me, this
error: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
candidate 1: TypeValue TypeValue::operator*(const long int&)
candidate 2: operator*(float, size_t) <built-in>

Comment: I didn't advise providing a TypeValue-long overload for operator*, did I? Provide FEWER conversions and FEWER overloads. The only operator* you should provide is this: <<TypeValue operator*(TypeValue const&) const;>> It's a const method that accepts a const reference and returns a value. (Don't return a reference.) Then, like I said before, type-cast (index - first_index) to be type T, at which point the compiler will construct a TypeValue object from that difference and multiply it with the first TypeValue object you have.

Answer (score 2):

I would change all the conversion operators to named functions so that:

```
operator long() const;
```

becomes

```
long ToLong() const;
```

Implicit conversiopns via cast operators cause all sorts of problems, and my own programming standards bans their use.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to know what is T.  It looks like you are instancing an XVector using some type (like unsigned char, for instance) that can be converted into all those types you see, and the compiler does not know which one to choose.

Comment: In this case, it is quite clear.  There are lots of implicit conversions from TypeValue and the compiler does not know which one to choose.  In fact, I don't understand how could this ever compile under gcc 3.2

Comment: This code compiles without errors or warnings in gcc 3.2.3, which still amuses me!